# How can I access with JS nonstandard tags in a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I wish to develop some kind of external API which will include users putting some nonstandard tags on their pages (which I will then replace with the correct HTML). For example:

```
<body>
...
...
   <LMS:comments></LMS:comments>
...
...
...
</body>
```

Hoe can I target and **replace** the `<LMS:comments></LMS:comments>` part?

Comment: I've edited your post: I believe the word you're looking for is "nonstandard". ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use getElementsByTagName as usual to get the element.

You cannot change the tag name, you will have to replace the entire element.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2vcjm/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use regular expressions.

Take a look at this page to get started:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

That whole website is a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your document is valid XHTML (as opposed to just HTML), you can use XSLT to parse it.

There are JavaScript XSLT libraries, such as [Google's AJAXSLT](http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/).

Barring that, you will need to extract the relevant part of the DOM, take the value of "innerHTML" for the contents, and replace the custom tags using JavaScript's regex and `replace()` function.

However, this sort of processing is usually done server-side, by passing your custom "HTML+" through some sort of templating/enrichment engine (which will also use XSLT or HTML parsers or worst case regexes).

Comment: The purpose (like FB and Dojo) is to give users the most simplest of API integration into their pages...